# Node.js hosting with Socket.io client support?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I made a socket.io client app which connects to my socket.io server and then they communicate whatever they need to.

When I do it locally on one machine or even on two different local machines, everything works fine. So I tried to deploy the client on [cloud9](http://c9.io) and it keeps throwing this error:

```
net.js:540
    connectReq = self._handle.connect(address, port);
Error: No local connects allowed for security purposes
    at connect (net.js:540:31)
    at net.js:607:9
    at Array.0 (dns.js:88:18)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

The client code is, *where [ip-address] is my servers IP address*:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
socket = io.connect('[ip-address]', {
    port: 1337
});
```

Is there a way to run such a socket.io client at c9.io?

Did they block it because of [this article](http://www.ngenuity-is.com/blog/2011/nov/1/doing-evil-with-the-cloud-9-ide-and-socketio/)?

**Are there any free node.js hosting solutions where one could run a socket.io client application like the one above?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com) is currently free node.js hosting solution where everything works (including [socket.io](http://socket.io))

Comment: yeah, I tried registering at nodejitsu twice and both times could not confirm my email because: "We've hit our limit today. Please try again later."

Comment: Please join #nodejitsu in irc.freenode.net and ask, support team will be happy to give you an invite.

Comment: Did that yesterday, had no chance to actually deploy the app and try t because of work, but as soon as I do that I will mark your answer as accepted one :)

Comment: hmmm... i created an app and deployed it, but it's not including the dependencies even though i have specifie socket.io and socket.io-client in the package.json file...

Comment: interesting. Do you mind gisting your package.json? Also, are you running `jitsu deploy` in the same directory as your package.json? I suggest visiting #nodejitsu on Freenode so I can help you faster. (feel free to ping me)

Comment: @CodeRarity: I don't mind sharing anything since I am now at the stage where I just need to connect, no logic or app specific stuff is there before that step is completed :)
- package.json: http://pastebin.com/7iA6DB3J
- yes, i'm running `jitsy deploy` in the same dir as the package.json

Comment: btw, this is error I get now, which tells me that at least the dependencies now work:
`error:  Error: socket hang up
error:      at createHangUpError (http.js:1115:15)
error:      at Socket.onend (http.js:1214:27)
error:      at TCP.onread (net.js:389:26)`

Comment: Yes, they work. If you have any troubles, please ask our support team in #nodejitsu at irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs you could create a free Heroku account. You wont have access to a database, and you're limited in resources, but if the app is small enough and efficient enough it could suffice.

Comment: fyi, i didn't give you the minus... but i am giving you a plus to neutralize it because the answer is IMO a legit one even though i like the other solution much better...

Comment: I didn't give a minus either, but perhaps it was because [Heroku only supports socket.io in long polling mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)

Comment: Now heroku support websocket :)

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift uses Port 8080 and Heroku 3000.

The ***Client*** code has to be like this:

```
// Wrong!:
// mySocket = io.connect(host, port);

// Right:
mySocket = io();
mySocket.on(....);
```

The ***Server*** code has to look like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('path/to/public/html'));
server.listen(8080); // OpenShift 8080, Heroku 3000

io.on(...);
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets#create-a-socket-io-client